# ExoPlayer(Xamarin) can't open http link - how fix it?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, exoplayer

I use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/Baseflow/ExoPlayerXamarin) in my Xamarin project. And I cant play music from http link in my app. This is my code:

```
SimpleExoPlayer _player;

    void InitPlayer()
    {
        var mediaUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://server5.radio-streams.net:8065/index.html?sid=1");
        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(Platform.CurrentActivity);
        trackSelector.SetParameters(trackSelector.BuildUponParameters().SetMaxVideoSizeSd());
        DefaultRenderersFactory renderersFactory = new DefaultRenderersFactory(Platform.CurrentActivity);
        IMediaSource mediaSource = BuildMediaSource(mediaUri);
        _player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(Platform.CurrentActivity, renderersFactory).SetTrackSelector(trackSelector).Build();
        _player.Prepare(mediaSource, false, false);
    }
    
    private IMediaSource BuildMediaSource(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(Platform.CurrentActivity, "ExoplayerTest");
        return new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).CreateMediaSource(uri);
    }

    private IMediaSource BuildDashMediaSource(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(Platform.CurrentActivity, "ExoplayerTest");
        DashMediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
        return mediaSourceFactory.CreateMediaSource(uri);
    }

    private IMediaSource BuildHlsMediaSource(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ExoplayerTest");
        IMediaSource hlsMediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).SetAllowChunklessPreparation(true).CreateMediaSource(uri);
        return hlsMediaSource;
    }
    
     public void Play()
    {
        if (_player == null)
            InitPlayer();
        _player.PlayWhenReady = true;
    }
```

I tried three method - BuildMediaSource, BuildDashMediaSource, BuildHlsMediaSource. But I am getting errors:

But for each method I get different errors:

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors
[ExoPlayerImplInternal]   com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, AmrExtractor, Ac4Extractor, FlacExtractor) could read the stream.

com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: Input does not start with the #EXTM3U header.

could read the stream
```

I understand that the point is in the link, but how can I fix it?
Any advice, I would be very grateful

Comment: it doesn't sound like the urls you are trying use a format that is supported by the player.  I just pasted one in my browser and it is an HTML page with an embedded player, not a direct link to the stream

Comment: by going through the url's elements, it seems the url you may want to use would be "http://server5.radio-streams.net:8065/stream?type=http&nocache=82696"

Since the url you have above is feeding the player a html page, you would either need to construct a way to extract the actual media playback url from that page and then feed to the player, OR feed the player an appropriate media url from the start.